# Cordova App only starts after 'cordova run android', not by tapping icon on tablet

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

My app starts wonderfull when I directly deploy it on the tablet via `cordova run android`.

However, If I leave the app and come back by tapping the app icon on android, the app fails to start (displays the same screen I ususally get when I deployed a JS syntax error). How can I detect that or solve that?

Comment: Have you seen the logcat ?

Comment: logcat needs root access rights which I dont have and cannot get.